# How can I decompress live streaming data with DeflateStream?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an event that gets fired when I receive data. The data received is a segment of a large compressed stream.

Currently, I maintain a `MemoryStream` and am calling `Write` on it whenever I receive data. However, to decompress this data I need to wrap a `DeflateStream` around it. The problem is that when you call `Read` on the `DeflateStream`, it reads zero bytes!

This is because the `DeflateStream.BaseStream` is the `MemoryStream` I just wrote to, so the `MemoryStream.Position` has been updated, for both reading **and** writing.

Is there an alternative to calling `MemoryStream.Seek(-bytesJustWritten, SeekOrigin.Current)` after every single `MemoryStream.Write`?

I need to be able to read the decompressed bytes in real-time without waiting for closure of the stream.

I thought I could just use two `MemoryStream` objects, one for buffering my input and then one to copy into and then read from, but I quickly realized that it would present the same problem; you cannot write to a stream and then read from it without first seeking.

Comment: I solved that problem by creating what I called `ProducerConsumerStream`. It's a custom object with a fixed-size circular buffer that implements the `Stream` interface. You write to one side and read from the other. See [Building a new type of stream](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852)

Comment: @JimMischel You should've added that as an answer :)

Comment: If I'd had something to add to the article, I would have made it an answer. But link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @JimMischel Absolutely, link only answers are discouraged. However! You don't need to make it just a link. It is perfectly reasonable to extract the important content as a quote and provide the link as a source and reference, as long as the answer is self sustaining and doesn't completely rely on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using one `MemoryStream` and calling `MemoryStream.Seek(-bytesJustWritten, SeekOrigin.Current)` after each time `MemoryStream.Write` was invoked.

This reset the position of the stream to allow for the data just decompressed to be read and later overwritten, while preserving the state of the `DeflateStream`.